# Printing 2d fresnel zone plate

Tags: optics, waves, geometric-optics, lenses

Recently my teacher asked me to create a Fresnel zone plate (Fresnel lens to be accurate).
I wanted to print it using a laser printer with a resolution of 1200*1200 dpi. I know that i should block even or odd zones in order to focus the light. The problem is using r_n = (f * z * n)^(1/2), the zone radiuses are so small that for z = 10m and n = 18, the radius is still under 1 cm. I was wondering if anyone can suggest me a solution to make a Fresnel zone plate for visible light that is bigger than this? Due to my printer's resolution, I cannot go under 0.02 millimeter accuracy.

Comment: FYI: A Fresnel zone plate is _not_ the same thing as a [Fresnel _lens_](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens). The man has more than one invention to his credit.

Comment: A comment: the equation for Fresnel zone $r_n = \sqrt{\lambda z n}$, do by "f" you mean a wavelength?